# Non interacting complex unit

Tags: cv.complex-variables, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, bessel-functions, wave-equation

How to work with two non interacting complex units say i and j. These two imaginary complex unit represent different quantities. For example i is for periodicity in theta and j is for frequency or time harmonic. I am sure this problem has been dealt with before but where and what to look for. 
The current problem is in wave propagation and elastic waves. If an elastic wave propagates in a homogenous isotropic media has the following general solutions of the displacement potentials can be determined by applying Fourier expansion with respect to $\theta$
 . The solution is
$$
\varphi=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left\{ J_{n}\left(k_{L}r\right)\begin{array}{c}
A_{n}^{(1)}\end{array}+H_{n}^{(1)}\left(k_{L}r\right)\begin{array}{c}
A_{n}^{(2)}\end{array}\right\} e^{i\left(n\theta\right)}e^{j\omega t}
$$
$$
  \psi=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left\{ J_{n}\left(k_{s}r\right)\begin{array}{c}
A_{n}^{(3)}\end{array}+H_{n}^{(1)}\left(k_{s}r\right)\begin{array}{c}
A_{n}^{(4)}\end{array}\right\} e^{i\left(n\theta\right)}e^{j\omega t}
$$

where $J_{n}\left(.\right)$
  is Bessel function of the first kind and $H_{n}^{(1)}\left(.\right)$
  is Hankel function of the first kind. $A_{n}$ potential displacement expanded amplitudes.
The issue arises more in programming and dealing with complex numbers. Is it due to i or j?

Comment: If you want the two imaginary not to interact, does their product satisfy some relations? Do you want $ij=ji$, $ij=-ji$ or something else?

Comment: yes $$ij=ij, ji=ji$$

Comment: What do you mean? Your comment must have a typo; otherwise it says nothing.

Comment: Sorry I mean relations for example $$ij=ji$$ are maintained. Is this topic covered in Mathematics. Where can I find more information about it?

Comment: I have never seen this kind of a ring. Maybe your could ask at MSE if someone knows a name for the ring of numbers $a+bi+cj+dij$, $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$ with $ij=ji$: http://math.stackexchange.com/